# How to compare fields only if the first is not empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm creating a form to edit user data that also allows changing the password (if entered by the user). I just don't know how to use jQuery Validate to check if password matches the password confirmation, if and only if the password field is not empty.

I've searched through stackoverflow and found something about the `skip_or_fill_minimum` method of jQuery Validate, however it is not working as I need.

You may check a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/u6DK5/3/

```
$(function() {
   $('#form').validate({
       debug: true,
       rules: {
            pwd: {
                minlength: 5,
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".pw"]
            },
            confirmPwd: {
                equalTo: '#NewPassword',
                skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".pw"]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pwd: {
                minlength: 'Password must have at least 5 characters'
            },
            confirmPwd: {              
                equalTo: 'Password and confirmation do not match'
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="pw" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="confirmPwd">Confirm:</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPwd" name="confirmPwd" class="pw" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule, nor do you need to create a custom method.

When the field is not `required`, then you can leave them both blank.  Simply by using `equalTo` on the second field will force the user to make it match.

- Leave the first field blank, then the second can be blank.
- Put something in the first field, then the second must match.

Your code was not working properly because your `equalTo` rule was set to match `#NewPassword`, yet you did not have any `input` element in your HTML with `id="NewPassword"`.  Change it to the `id` of the field you're trying to match; in this case, `#pwd`, and it works perfectly fine.

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/nMjAy/

```
$(function () {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            pwd: {
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirmPwd: {
             // equalTo: '#NewPassword' // <-- no such ID in your HTML
                equalTo: '#pwd'         
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pwd: {
                minlength: 'Password must have at least {0} characters'
            },
            confirmPwd: {
                equalTo: 'Password and confirmation do not match'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="pw" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="confirmPwd">Confirm:</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPwd" name="confirmPwd" class="pw" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```